# How to move freely a multiple cropped shapes from an image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, pathfinder, crop

I'm trying to crop multiple circles from an image. I grouped the circles and applied : 
Object -> compound path -> make; whereas the image I made it a clipping mask, and then used the pathfinder tools to do Exclude. 
Thankfully, I obtained multiple circles which has inside the part of the image I want.

However, I want to be able to move each circle with the image inside freely from the other circles but the move seems restricted with all the circles has to move together as I need to move all the circles together. How can I make each circles (shape) into an independent image/shape , please?

It seems an easy thing but it made very frustrated as I've been trying for days.

Many Thanks,
Batool

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Is there any chance you could post an image showing what you are trying to do, or where it goes wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a group of circles as one big mask on one image.

Instead you need to have multiple copies of the image, each with one circle as mask.

Then you can move the circular images around independently.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Group Selection Tool** to select each circle clicking at its path and move

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried the Group Selection Tool and I know how to move them in the way you kindly illustrated. I'm sorry it seems that I didn't explain my question very well. As you can see in the GIF you kindly added. Once the circle is moved, the image that is behind the circle change according to the place of the circle from the image. I want the image to be fixed behind the circle. In other words, the first time I clipped the circles with the image behind, I want to make each circle an independent image. I'm not sure if this make sense at all. If not, please let me know.